# Change page number of manually added TOC entry without adding blank pages

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, page-numbering, tocloft

I have a main LaTeX document and an external PDF that I used to include with `pdfpages` (and it looks great!). But, now I want to insert TOC entries to reference sections and subsections inside external the `.pdf`. I'm doing it like:

```
\newcounter{page-backup}
\setcounter{page-backup}{\value{page}}
% begin to fake-numerate
\setcounter{page}{106}
% increment chapter counter and reset section and subsection
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
% add chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter} CHAPTER}
% add section
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection} Section}
% add more...    
\setcounter{page}{125}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection} Section}
% add some stuff
\addtocounter{tottables}{42}
\addtocounter{totfigures}{3}
% restore main page numeration
\setcounter{page}{\value{page-backup}}
```

But, in the TOC I'm getting all entries on page 106 (first page of fake enumeration). How can I manually change the page numbers of inserted TOC entries? As I know there is a `\addtocontents` but it is very manual. I have to manually format every entry...

Comment: In your penultimate sentence you state that you would like to avoid manual formatting, but in the sentence before you ask how to solve the issue manually. So, please clarify which of the two options you would like to pursue. Both isn't possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a partial answer to the question

In a similar situation I included the individual sections separated, using something like:

```
...
\tableofcontents
... initial part (with no tricks)

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{...ext sec title 1}    
\includepdf[pages={1-20}]{external.pdf}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{...ext sec title 2}
\includepdf[pages={21-30}]{external.pdf}

... for all the external pdf units

...continuation (no tricks)
```

This way LaTeX does the work (no fake paging needed).

I like to have the external pdf unnumbered and in the add the following in the includepdf instruction:

```
\includepdf[pages=...,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{...}
```

(adaptations needed) in order to add page numbers to the external pdf.

(Suggestion: write a newcommand `\externalPDFunit{type}{pages}{title}{file}` )